# What's the point of writing on a cockpit window?

Tags: pilots, windows

Why would a pilot write on the cockpit window like this?

[image: Pilot writing on cockpit window]

From: [source](http://www.iefimerida.gr/news/148209/%CE%B5%CF%81%CE%B5%CF%85%CE%BD%CE%B5%CF%82-%CE%B3%CE%B9%CE%B1-%CF%84%CE%BF-%CF%87%CE%B1%CE%BC%CE%AD%CE%BD%CE%BF-boeing-%CE%B5%CE%BD%CF%84%CF%8C%CF%80%CE%B9%CF%83%CE%B1%CE%BD-%CE%BD%CE%AD%CE%B1-%CE%B1%CE%BD%CF%84%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%B5%CE%AF%CE%BC%CE%B5%CE%BD%CE%B1-%CF%83%CF%84%CE%BF%CE%BD-%CE%B9%CE%BD%CE%B4%CE%B9%CE%BA%CF%8C-%CF%83%CF%80%CE%B5%CF%8D%CE%B4%CE%BF%CF%85%CE%BD-%CE%BF%CE%B9-%CE%B4%CE%B9%CE%B1%CF%83%CF%8E%CF%83%CF%84%CE%B5%CF%82)

Comment: I think this is used mostly by SAR or other military pilots when running grid work.

Comment: @RonBeyer: that makes sense, since the picture is about the search for the missing Malasia flight. So, normal commercial pilots would not do this?

Comment: poor man's HUD.

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE! Please post the source of your image.

Comment: @FreeMan: done, but it's in Greek.

Comment: @PierreB so what? You should always post it. ML knows how to (or at least give a (bad) approximation of a translation). Moreover, I am Greek, I can help if someone wants. iEfimerida stands for electronic newspaper.

Comment: "*Squadron leader Brett McKenzie marks the name of another search aircraft on the windscreen of a Royal New Zealand Air Force P-3K2 Orion aircraft searching for missing Malaysian Airlines flight MH370 over the southern Indian Ocean. Photo: Reuters*" ([source](http://www.scmp.com/news/asia/southeast-asia/article/1993247/officials-call-search-missing-malaysia-airlines-plane))

Comment: @PierreB you may include in the question the context (I suppose it is explained in the paper linked, but extracting the relevant part could help understand the question's context)

Answer (score 38):

If you use a grease pencil, it rubs off easily from glass

So you can save paper, not have to look down or hunt for the info, it won't fall on the floor, and if it's written in the center of the windshield, both pilots can see it